# Getting exception while running jmeter in jdk1.8 using ant

Tags: java, xml, xpath, ant, jmeter

I am getting this exception while running JMeter in JDK1.8 using ANT:

```None
D:\jmeter\build.xml:50: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\jmeter\build.xml:68: The following error occurred while executing this line:
: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\jmeter\build.xml:100: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\jmeter\build.xml:124: java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance()
failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.c
om/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.X
PathFactoryConfigurationException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xm
l.xpath.XPathFactory: jar:file:/D:/ant/lib/saxon9he.jar!/META-INF/services/javax
.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:2: Illegal configuration-file syntax
```

Comment: You're getting an exception - so what have you tried so far to debug it? There doesn't seem to be a question here. You haven't shown the code that is causing this. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The error stands for malformed `build.xml` file, there is a "good" one which lives in "extras" folder of your JMeter installation which you can use as a reference.

If you installed JMeter from somewhere else you can get the file from [JMeter SVN repo](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/extras/build.xml). Start with it, verify it works and modify it as required.

See **2. USE APACHE ANT** chapter of the [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for more details on running a JMeter test with Ant.

Answer (score 0):

I have explained using Ant + JMeter in the below link along with a sample project to download and try.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/